# Display text messages, an a graphviz (Digraph) generated pdf (independantely from the graph)

Tags: python, graphviz

Let's say I generated a pdf with the following graph, using python's graphviz lib (Digraph object):

[image]

And I want to display a text message saying "Hi", i.e. on the bottom left corner of the graph, that is empty. Can I tell graphviz to add messages to my pdf somehow?

Answer (score 0):

doing `dot.attr(label='Hi'))` displays a label in the bottom, which solves my problem